# Hide dropdown on click when using a js router

Tags: javascript, css

Given that my html/css is set up like below:

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">sub-link></a>
          <a href="#">sub-link></a>
          <a href="#">sub-link></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I "untrigger" or "untoggle" the hover state on `.dropdown` when a link inside `.dropdown-content` is clicked? I left the links as `href="#"` as this mimics the behavior of clicking a link using a js router (angular/react/vue) where clicking the link isn't actually a page change.

So the current effect is that you click a link and the page changes, but the dropdown content stays open. Desired effect is to have the dropdown-content close as soon as an `a` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Only using additional class like .hover:

```
.dropdown.hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

html (ng)

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-class="{ 'hover': ishover }" ng-mouseover="ishover=true">
<a href="#" ng-click="ishover=false">...</a>
```

or vanillajs classlist add on this events ...